# How to retrieve response of INSERT in supabase without execute

Tags: flutter, supabase

I tried to use the new system in my flutter application using the supabase_flutter: ^1.4.0 package

It works but I have no response about the insertion

```
final response = await supabase
      .from('order')
      .insert(tmp)
      ;
```

the response is always null.
For example how can I get the progressive id of my insertion in table order?

Answer (score 1):

I feel so dumb...

Simply adding the

> .select()

clause we will get the resoult from insert

So the complete code look like this

```
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> response  = await supabase
      .from('order')
      .insert(tmp)
      .select();
```